# Transforming a rectangle in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, transform

I have any transformation matrix, for example:

```
sig =[[2,1],[1,1]]
```

With this code, I could transform a circle with r=1:

```
import numpy as np
import math as mt
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

sig =[[2,1],[1,1]]

ndiv=100 
r=1.0
theta=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,ndiv)
x=r*np.cos(theta)
y=r*np.sin(theta)    

fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
ax.plot(x,y,'b.')

x_transf=np.zeros(ndiv)
y_transf=np.zeros(ndiv)

direc=np.zeros(ndiv)

N=np.zeros(ndiv)

v=[0.0,0.0]
w=[0.0,0.0]  
for i in range(ndiv): 
    v[0]=x[i]
    v[1]=y[i]

    w=np.dot(sig,v)     

    x_transf[i]=w[0] 
    y_transf[i]=w[1]

 N[i]=mt.sqrt(x_transf[i]**2+y_transf[i]**2)


 ax.plot(x_transf,y_transf,'g+')
 axis('equal')
 grid('on')
```

Now I need to transform a rectangle (square) using this tranformation matrix:

```
M = [[sqrt(th), -1.5*th],[2*sin(th),cos(th)]] #th is an angle between 0 and 2pi
```

Also find the angle that produces the biggest area. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how to apply the transformation.  As an example and a check I also applied a normal rotation (in red):

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import sin, cos, sqrt, pi

r0 = np.array([[.5, .2], [1.5,.2], [1.5,1.2], [.5,1.2], [.5,.2]])

th = .05*pi
R = np.array([[cos(th), -sin(th)], [sin(th), cos(th)]])
M = np.array([[sqrt(th), -1.5*th],[2*sin(th),cos(th)]])

r1 = R.dot(r0.T).T
r2 = M.dot(r0.T).T

plt.plot(r0[:,0], r0[:,1], "bo-")
plt.plot(r1[:,0], r1[:,1], "ro-")
plt.plot(r2[:,0], r2[:,1], "go-")
plt.xlim(-0.2, 1.8)
plt.ylim(-0., 2.)

plt.show()
```

As for finding the largest area, you could either derive this analytically, or numerically calculate the area of the rotated rectangle and maximize it, using, say, [scipy.optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html).